# How to clone UCM project?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am having a project which is to be released this month. My CC admin advised to clone the project in separate project as we want to do another parallel development.

How to clone a project from another project (from particular recommended baseline)?

If there are few more changes done in source project (Which may be done another few weeks), i need to sync it withe new project. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly a "clone": you just define a new UCM project, with at least one Strea, called by default an "[integration Stream](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pln_strm_int_confg.htm)".

However, in your case, you could for your new parallel development (ie your new UCM project), use only that one "Integration" stream, in which case it wouldn't play really the role of "integrating", but would be a "development" stream.
That wouldn't prevent you, in this new parallel development project, to recreate whatever hierarchy of Stream you would need.
Each UCM project has always at least one Stream. Then it is up to you to create sub-streams as needed.

You would rebase that first empty Stream with the baseline of your choice (put on one of the Stream of the first project)

For keeping both projects in sync, you would **deliver** from one project to the other.
You need though to set the [**deliver policy**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_ucmproj_policies.htm) "[`allow interproject deliver to project or stream`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pol_dlvr_nndflt.htm)"

[image: inter-project deliver policy]

Comment: What does it mean "but you can use it for any role you want"? Can you please rephrase that alone?

Comment: @Samselvaprabu I have edited/expended on the "role" part. "Integration" is a convention. If you have only one Stream in your new project, it can play the role of a simple "development" Stream if you want it to.

Comment: Do you mean that we can't create all the streams as it is in source project by mentioning 'We can't exactly clone'? I do not require to clone all the streams. Just one integration stream initially will do good

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: yes, you can create a new project with just the Integration Stream (anyway, you always have to create at least one Stream, the root one, called by convention "Integration", for the UCM project to be usable).